# fast method to extract column data in Excel .xlsx to array python

Tags: python, arrays, excel

Hi I'm using a loop to extract data from a column in excel into an array. Because I have lots of data it takes a bit of time. I was wondering if there was a way to do it quicker?

using a function:
def xlscol(fname, sheetname, col, r1, r2):

## """

```
col is a string of the column to get data from
fname is filename, col is column as a letter string, r1, r2 are row 1 to row 2, sheetname
"""
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname, data_only=True) 
ws = wb[sheetname] #get worksheet

results =[]
for row in range(r1,r2):
    for column in col:  
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        results.append(ws[cell_name].value) 

return results
```

Comment: Pandas has a read_excel function. Pandas is a very commonly used library for data wrangling and is not a heavy dependency. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Pandas is a pretty good answer. To add another possibility though, you could use `win32com` to connect directly to excel's component object model. There can be a lot of quirks to using this method, but it can also be much more flexible than pandas in terms of manipulating excel. Just try to read ranges of cells at a time rather than individually (individually is very slow).